# Is it possible to use .trc, .trb or .cap files in blender?

Tags: animation, file-format, motion-capture, conversion

I've recently recovered some mocap data files, but I do not have access to MoBu currently and was hoping to use Blender to display my data and attach to a rig to add to my portfolio. Unfortunately, I have not found a way to do this with just .TRC, .TRB, or .CAP data. I know Blender can technically read the data because TRC data when I import my FBX files I see it in the item list, however I cannot see it displayed. Even just being able to see the markers displayed would be a huge step forward. Thanks.

Comment: by trc do you mean [this format](https://alinen.github.io/MotionScriptTools/notes/TRCFormat.html).  It looks like it would be easy to convert but there doesn't appear to currently be a blender converter. You might want to check with the [OpenSim Project](https://simtk.org/projects/opensim) to see if they have a converter to a format blender can handle such as BVH

Comment: I do not, I meant tracking data recorded in Cortex. I've seen this come up a lot it has made my search quite difficult lol

Answer (score -1):

I stumbled upon this tool. Here is a link to 2015 Free Motion Capture Tool that reads cd3 files. It also shows trc, cap and tom files too.

https://www.mocap.me/mocap_free_tool.html

I am trying to convert c3d files to bvh or fbx, I have found a c3d converter for blender, but it does not work properly.